# Is it possible to capture javascript errors in QML WebView?

Tags: qt, webview, qml

I'm building a QML application using: Qt 5.1/QtQuick 2.0/QtWebKit 3.0 which needs an embedded webview.  Now I also want to capture javascript errors which may happen on the webpage.  I've seen this topic https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/18143/ which comes close but it isnt a QML application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0
```

It contains

```
WebView.experimental.evaluateJavaScript()
```

[Documentation is here](http://rschroll.github.io/beru/2013/08/21/qtwebview.experimental.html) and [an example of using it is here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-apps/snowshoe/source/35afbe295043bd3e27357b8e987ec19b54bfd8c8:src/desktop/qml/PageWidget.qml#L60-77)

Comment: Please don't copy-paste information from other websites when editing tag wikis. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating [something useful to this community *specifically*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/), and be sure to attribute the original author. Thanks!